# Action Fetch only works the first time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

First of all thank you for any help you can give me. I want to be able to dynamically activate/deactivate the status of a partner.

[image]

On each status change, a Bootstrap modal opens

[image]

The status changes correctly but the screen is grayed out as if my modal window was still open without modal

[image]

I can't see my error to resolve this behavior. I'm still new to fetch so any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code

```js
// Activation ou désactivation dynamique d'un partenaire

//On boucle sur les input
document.querySelectorAll(".form-switch-statut-partenaire input").forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("change", () => {

        //On récupère l'url de la route edit-statut
        const Url = input.dataset.path;

        const Modal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')
        const Footer = Modal.getElementsByClassName('modal-footer')[0].children[1]

        Footer.addEventListener("click", () => {

            //On lance la requête ajax
            fetch(Url)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json()
            }).then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                const content = document.querySelector('#formCheck');
                content.innerHTML = data.content;
            }).catch((err) => console.log('Erreur : '+ err));     
         })
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe you should just refresh the page after changing status

Comment: It would be great but I'm trying in vain without knowing how to go about it. Could you help me in this direction?

Comment: I think you can close the `Modal` after `content.innerHTML = data.content`

Comment: I managed to close the modal with this line:
```$("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" });```
Now it works but if I try to change the status again the second time doesn't work. Do I have to do another loop somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Holà amigo ,
you should basically try something like this

when you start your request ,

on success, if you use something like this

```
 onSuccess: () => {
            onClose();
        }
```

that is for axios no idea for ajax

there must be something similar

you must also be able to add the close directly on your button

like this

```
  <Button onClick={() => onClose()}>
       oui
    </Button>
```

or something like that

I hope I have helped you a little

Neff

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your precious help.
However I solved the problem of the Modal.
Here is my code at the moment.

```js
// Activation ou désactivation dynamique d'un partenaire

//On boucle sur les input
document.querySelectorAll(".form-switch-statut-partenaire input").forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("change", () => {

        //On récupère l'url de la route edit-statut
        const Url = input.dataset.path;

        const Modal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')
        const Footer = Modal.getElementsByClassName('modal-footer')[0].children[1]

        Footer.addEventListener("click", () => {
            
            $("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({ type: "click" });
            //On lance la requête ajax
            fetch(Url)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json()
            }).then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                const content = document.querySelector('#formCheck');
                content.innerHTML = data.content;
            }).catch((err) => console.log('Erreur : '+ err));     
         })
    });
});
```

It works the first time but as soon as I click on the input again the modal opens but the action no longer works. I need to refresh the page. And I'm stuck on this issue...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).